# Dockerfile CMD ignored arguments

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I'm trying to run an containerized image locally using google cloud shell docker daemon:

```
> PORT=8080 && docker run -p 9090:${PORT} -e PORT=${PORT} gcr.io/gbl-tpd-endetec-dev1/simplest-helloworld
```

However i got this error :

```
> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"app.py\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

When I check container status and in the COMMAND column, i don't have what i expect :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                    NAMES
977b0ee4b04d        gcr.io/gbl-tpd-endetec-dev1/simplest-helloworld          "app.py"                 11 minutes ago      Created                        0.0.0.0:9090->8080/tcp   youthful_williams
```

I should have `"python ./app.py"` since I've written it in my Dockerfile CMD instruction :

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

Can someone help me about what I am missing?

Comment: No, but according to the documentation found on official python docker image it is not needed : [python - Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) in `How to Use this Image` section. *Comment answering deleted comment "Do you have an ENTRYPOINT defined?"*

Comment: Are you sure you're running the right image? I don't see a _tag_ being used in the image name `gcr.io/gbl-tpd-endetec-dev1/simplest-helloworld`, so are you sure you're not using an older image that you have locally that does not have the CMD set correctly?

Comment: In my Container Registry, I've got a single repository filled with a single image. So I guess it is using the correct image (I have deleted the repository itself before building)

Comment: If you aren't sure, it's worth checking that you're using exactly the right image (by SHA) that you expect to. The dockerfile CMD you posted doesn't match what you're seeing in `docker ps` and I would rule out the most obvious possible causes first—like using an older image that had a different CMD.

Comment: It works with the tag. I still don't understand how it is using the wrong image since I can only see a single one

Comment: If you're deploying this locally, then you've got the image cached, even if it's not in the repo.